# can i change incoming mail label in outlook to another label using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, outlook, outlook-addin

> I am creating outlook add ons. I want when mail come inbox then change
>   the label, i use **Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(callBack)**
>   method but in work only when **outlook web app open**. I want
>   Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(callBack) call **everytime**
>   when mail comes in **Inbox.** 
>   If there is  ant Outlook **Rest Api** available for that problem.

```
private void Phishing_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
        {
            outlookApp = new Outlook.Application();
            inboxFolder = outlookApp.ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
            deleterFolder = outlookApp.ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderJunk);
            mailItems = inboxFolder.Items;//.Restrict("[Unread]=true");
            mailItems.Sort("[ReceivedTime]", true);
            inboxFolder.Items.ItemAdd += new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(CallFunction);
        }


private void CallFunction(object data)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("call function");
         }
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. What label?

Comment: LABEL MEANS INBOX, DRAFT,SPAM @DmitryStreblechenko

Comment: That is called folder in Outlook. If you want to move an item to a different folder, call MailItem.Move passing MAPIFolder object as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlook add-in can work only when Outlook application is running. It seems you can't get what you wish using an Outlook add-in - find an alternative way. If you run Outlook against on-site Exchange server try to create a so called transport agent for Exchange.